# issue with my ir.ui.view while creating a wizard from action

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i have an issue with my wizard.
i have an action  created by me,which is under sales menu in module sale.
when i click on action i need to display a wizard..i am not getting proper output with my code.in my code, when i click on action it will display a create wizard and after i clicking on that wizard only , i am getting the proper wizard which is i defined in my ir.ui.view.i need to display my ir.ui.view directly and i do not need an intermediate wizard..pls help me.`

```
    <record id="wizard_view" model="ir.ui.view" >
        <!--<field name="name" >REPORT</field >-->
        <field name="model">filter_wizard</field>
        <field name="view_type">tree,form</field>
        <!--<field name="target">new</field>-->
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="filter options">
                <field name="selection_field" />
                <!--<field name="customer"/>-->
                <field name="date_from" />
                <field name="date_to"/>
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;<group>&ndash;&gt;-->
                <!--&lt;!&ndash;<label string="This operation resets the sale order"/>&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;</group>&ndash;&gt;-->
            <footer>
                <button name="filter_opt" type="object" string="CONFIRM" />
            </footer>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_pr">
        <!--<field name="name" >REPORT FILTER</field >-->

        <field name="view type">form</field>
        <field name="res_model">filter_wizard</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem action="action_pr" id="menu_product" name="report" parent="base.menu_sales" sequence="9"/>




</data>
```

`from openerp import models, fields,api

class Filter_wizars(models.Model):

```
_name = 'filter_wizard'


selection_field = fields.Selection((('n','invoiced',), ('c','back log')),'invoiced/backlog')
customer = fields.Many2one('res.partner','customer')
date_from = fields.Datetime('From')
date_to = fields.Datetime('To')
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action view you are repeat the same things  `view_type` as twice in menu action attribute and do not used to make space between view and type (view_type) attribute.

You have to replace the below action and upgrade the module in your system

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_pr">
        <field name="name" >REPORT FILTER</field >
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="res_model">filter_wizard</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    </record>
```

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: is it necessary to add target in both action record and view record?

Comment: yes because hear target is indicate that the the form will pop as generate the new view or as pop up view inside same view like other form sale,purchase etc..

Comment: @ DaSaDiYa ChaiTAnYa:  is ther any room available for chat in odoo

Comment: not now but definitely in future some one make for us. do u have any Question for me

Comment: yes but hear if you have 1000 reputation on stack then after u can create your own chat room  and if u have 25 or more reputation the u can connect with group chat on room